# How to parse the XML output from Wire-shark to Obix?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, wireshark, niagara-4

I have getting some XML data from a server. The all data are an alerts, those are generating automatically. I can only see those data using wireshark software. I want to take all the XML data as Obix XML/Obix watch, because I need to get all the alerts in my third party system (Niagara N4), Niagara supports Obix data. I don't have any idea about XML/Obix. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is generating OBIX data encoded in XML, then yes Niagara can consume that using its OBIX driver.  Niagara will expect to connect to an OBIX server that complies with the specification, so if all you have is something generating XML objects, you will need to write a server that serves data according to the OBIX specification.